# MS Teams bot displaying time in user's timezone

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I'm building a Microsoft Teams bot using their REST APIs. The bot needs to send status of an event like `Started at 1:43 PM` or `Ended at 5:30 PM`. This information is to be sent to channels, which will quite naturally have users belonging to different timezones. Is there a way to send the ISO_8601 formatted datetime text (or any other format) and let MS Teams present the time in user's locale and timezone?

Comment: Something similar to what Slack does like here https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#date-formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adaptive cards does provide a way to do it. `TIME` function takes the ISO_8601 formatted datetime text and presents the time to the end user in their locale and timezone.

Format: `{{TIME(ISO_8601_Formatted_Date_String)}}`

More detail - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/text-features#datetime-formatting-and-localization

The sad part is this works only inside attachment cards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of anything similar in Teams, at least not in a normal text message. As a possible alternative suggestion, perhaps have the datetime be in UTC, tell the users that's the case, and make the text itself a hyperlink to a web page that shows the time(s) in the user's local time.

In your webpage, you can get the user's timezone using

`Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`

and from there lookup and calculate the offset, to show them the relevant time.

To actually make the text in your bot's message a hyperlink, you need to send back an Adaptive Card and use Markdown format for the url, which looks similar this: [My Link] (https://whatever.com) (but without a space, so it would be ]( <- I put a space in here,  otherwise StackOverflow itself things this is a real link!)